# Marklogic Url-Rewriter is not working and need help to properly configure

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I have Xquery file which will upload the text file and pass it to the url rewriter (which was pre configured in the server configuration earlier) and rerouting the incoming request to the corresponding location. At rewriter.xqy, my options config are not working as expected. I am not sure how to debug the code and find out the issue.

Please find the code below:

```
form.xqy
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body> 
<form name="media" action="/action/action-media/action-media.xqy" 
 method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<h1>UploadInputFile</h1>
<p><label>File to upload  <input type="file" class="name" 
 name="uploadfile" size="50" multiple="false"/></label></p> 
 <p><input type="submit" value="submit"/></p> 
 </form> 
 </body>
 </html>  

rewriter.xqy

let $rest-request := rest:rewrite($requests:options)
return if($rest-request)
          then $rest-request
        else xdmp:get-request-url()

requests.xqy
<request uri="fn:concat("^",$BEGPOINT,'/([a-zA-Z]{5})-([a-zA-Z]{5}. 
(^xqy.))" endpoint="{$ENDPOINT}">
<uri-param name="uploadfile">$1</uri-param>
<http method="POST"/>
</request>

Url-Rewriter (ML-admin-config):
/action/action-media/sys/rewriter.xqy
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: Don't know exactly how far you are with the re-writer code, but [XQRS](http://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs) may help you simplify your re-writer code, including [File Uploads via Forms](http://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs/docs/form-file-uploads). There's a video introduction on YouTube about using [RESTXQ for RESTful Web Services](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8vqfrONPXA) too.

Comment: @charlesfoster : i can be able to reroute using rewriter. I fixed it. I am just verifying the URI param name and  not able to read the file in uri-param . I am also thinking  how to pass the parameter to read the file ?  do i need to use the xdmp:get-request-field or xdmp:get-request-body. can

Comment: When i am rewriting the request to the action-media.xqy, i am getting the method 405 method not allowed .

Comment: To debug something like this generally needs a *complete* example of all the code and configuration, input data example and full system and app logs.  There is simply too much involved to offer a useful 'guess'

Comment: I removed the customized url rewriter and  moved with work around option.Now its working good. I am not able to identify few options , like  read the file data with URI-Params option and did not find any development examples at Marklogic blog for custom url-rewriter.